# How do I re organize the rows of a matrix using a vector in Octave?

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, matrix, octave

I am trying to achieve something stupid here and I am struck at this one point.

Say I have a matrix X which is 5 * 3 and I have a vector B which is 5 * 1

```
X = [6 5 3;
     4 5 6;
     3 8 9;
     7 8 9;
     1 2 3]

B = [1;
     5;
     4;
     2;
     3]
```

How do I reorganize my X using B to get the order of indexes as indicated in B.

What I want to happen is ..

```
X = someoperation(X, B)
```

and X should be

```
 X = [6 5 3;
      1 2 3;
      7 8 9;
      4 5 6;
      3 8 9]
```

I could write a function to do this but I see that inbuilt function are faster than functions that I write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any functions, this is a simple case of [subscript indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), a basic feature of the language:

```
X(B,:)
```

Comment: Matlab has [cody](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/) which you might find a useful, interactive way to learn. Otherwise the Matlab documentation is pretty comprehensive: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html

Comment: @Aditya Octave is almost identical to Matlab. The language basics are the same. Use the Matlab tutorials to learn the basics of Octave (which is a Matlab clone)